# How to properly use batch flag in snakemake to subset DAG

Tags: snakemake

I have a workflow written in snakemake that balloons at one point to a large number of output files. This happens because there are many combinations of my wildcards yielding on the order of 60,000 output files.

With this number of input files, DAG generation is very slow for subsequent rules to the point of being unusable. In the past, I've solved this issue by iterating with bash loops across subsetted configuration files where all but one of the wildcards is commented out. For example, in my case I had one wildcard (primer) that had 12 possible values. By running snakemake iteratively for each value of "primer", it divided up the workflow into digestible chunks (~5000 input files). With this strategy DAG generation is quick and the workflow proceeds well.

Now I'm interested in using the new `--batch` flag available in snakemake 5.7.4 since Johannes suggested to me on twitter that it should basically do the same thing I did with bash loops and subsetted config files.

However, I'm running into an error that's confusing me. I don't know if this is an issue I should be posting on the github issue tracker or I'm just missing something basic.

The rule my workflow is failing on is as follows:

```
rule get_fastq_for_subset:
    input:
        fasta="compute-workflow-intermediate/06-subsetted/{sample}.SSU.{direction}.{group}_pyNAST_{primer}.fasta",
        fastq="compute-workflow-intermediate/04-sorted/{sample}.{direction}.SSU.{group}.fastq"
    output:
        fastq=temp("compute-workflow-intermediate/07-subsetted-fastq/{sample}.SSU.{direction}.{group}_pyNAST_{primer}.full.fastq"),
        fastq_revcomp="compute-workflow-intermediate/07-subsetted-fastq/{sample}.SSU.{direction}.{group}_pyNAST_{primer}.full.revcomped.fastq"
    conda:
        "envs/bbmap.yaml"
    shell:
        "filterbyname.sh names={input.fasta} include=t in={input.fastq} out={output.fastq} ; "
        "revcompfastq_according_to_pyNAST.py --inpynast {input.fasta} --infastq {output.fastq} --outfastq {output.fastq_revcomp}"
```

I set up a target in my `all` rule to generate the output specified in the rule, then tried running snakemake with the batch flag as follows:

```
snakemake --configfile config/config.yaml --batch get_fastq_for_subset=1/20 --snakefile Snakefile-compute.smk --cores 40 --use-conda
```

It then fails with this message:

```
WorkflowError:
Batching rule get_fastq_for_subset has less input files than batches. Please choose a smaller number of batches.
```

Now the thing I'm confused about is that my input for this rule should actually be on the order of 60,000 files. Yet it appears snakemake getting less than 20 input files. Perhaps it's only counting 2, as in the number of input files that are specified by the rule? But this doesn't really make sense to me...

The source code for snakemake is here, showing how snakemake counts things but it's a bit beyond me:

https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/snakemake/dag.html

If anyone has any idea what's going on, I'd be very grateful for your help!

Best,
Jesse

Comment: Are you sure about how many times the rule would be called? What is the output of `snakemake -n | grep  get_fastq_for_subset`? At what number of batches does SnakeMake stop complaining?

Comment: @Maarten-vd-Sande - thanks for the reply. I just used a subsetted config file to check the output of the command you suggested. and here's the result: `4880   get_fastq_for_subset`. This is the number I expect. Snakemake only stops complaining when I have 2 batches, so it does seem like it's counting the two input files specified in the rule, not the number of possible inputs as determined by expanding the wildcards.

Comment: Seems like that should work... I would advise to make a minimal working example and add as issue on GitHub indeed.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Maarten, will do!

Comment: OK so I did submit an issue but this is a misapprehension on my part about how the batch flag works, see: https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/issues/98